# Error while running cordova build for ios : IONIC 1

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am facing below error while running `cordova buid ios`

```
IXME: Implement XCBuild support for macros in overriding parameters with condition sets:

        CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*] = iPhone Developer
(node:25566) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error code 1 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/**USER_NAME**/Documents/git/**APP_NAME**/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,**APP_NAME**.xcworkspace,-scheme,**APP_NAME**,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/**USER_NAME**/Documents/git/**APP_NAME**/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/**USER_NAME**/Documents/git/**APP_NAME**/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
(node:25566) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25566) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

`cordova version 8.0.0`

Comment: I have the same issue with cordova@9.0.0 on Mojave, with Xcode 11.2 (the latest version). Build works fine in Xcode.

Comment: Yeah! x-code build is just fine